# What differenciates browser.alarms.create from setTimeout/setInterval in WebExtensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, add-on

I am creating a WebExtension for browsers. So I found out about [the browser.alarms API](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/alarms/create). It basically allows you to set a (reoccurring or one-time) alarm and a callback will be fired.

Now, we've had such a feature this for a long time in JavaScript as in [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) and [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval). So **what is the difference** to these ones? Why or in what cases may I prefer the **one over the other**?

I mean the main difference is obvious: You can only refire it e.g. in minutes, not seconds. Although, I think with `when` you can also unregister and re-register it in millisecond precision, but I think the API may be intended for longer periods, i.e. minutes. (I am just guessing here.)
So why should I use it instead of a simple `setInterval`/`setTimeout` callback?

Comment: Presumably alarms persist across browser sessions.

Comment: @Emissary I doubt so, as that would strictly go against most WebExtension APIs that loose their state when you e.g. update the add-on or restart the browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- setTimeout/setInterval time span is limited by 2^31-1 = 2147483647 i.e. ~24 days. Values less than 0 or bigger than that are cast into int32 range, which can produce unexpected results.
- setTimeout/setInterval is part of standard DOM, not the [isolated world](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world), so when you use it inside a content script, the web page script can clear them accidentally via clearTimeout/clearInterval.
  <sup>Workaround: post a message to the background script so it sets the timer and sends a response upon finishing.</sup>
- [Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (those that have `"persistent": false` in manifest.json) won't wait for setTimeout / setInterval before unloading due to inactivity and won't wake up for such a timer so you can only use them for a very short time (currently the event pages are guaranteed to live for 5 seconds).

Within these designated limits you can safely use setTimeout/setInterval.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what has been posted, the alarm API seems to be more reliable:

> - if you setup alarm in the past, it will fire right away
> - if you setup future date and your PC wakes up from hibernation after the date, it will fire right after waking up
> - if you setup 8 hours from now, it will fire 8 hours from now (if your PC is on) no matter how long was your PC sleeping / hibernating in the meantime

See https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/how-reliable-are-alarms/40978/8?u=rugkx, thanks to [Juraj Masiar](https://discourse.mozilla.org/u/juraj.masiar/) from the Mozilla Community.

Answer (score 2):

To quote from the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/alarms):

> This is like setTimeout() and setInterval(), except that those functions don't work with background pages that are loaded on demand.